# Triplehead2go no signal to projectors

Tags: multiple-monitors, display-adapter

I have:

- Lenovo with Ryzen 5.
- One Triplehead2go
- 3x Optoma EH415ST projectors.

Laptop has 1 HDMI output which is connected to the Triplehead2go through the adaptor's DisplayPort input.

The matrox GXM from the powerdesk software is able to communicate with the projectors as the make and model is detected.

The issue is all 3 show `no signal detected`. I’m at a complete loss and would take any help I can.

Update: i plugged in the laptop today, turned on the projectors and two magically got image. Not sure what I’m missing for the 3ed one?

Comment: What is GXM? Edit your question instead of submitting a comment